# react-native ios No script URL provided

Tags: ios, react-native

I use this command to run react-native ios project. But there is an issue

> No script URL provided. Make sure the packager is running or you have
>   embedded a JS bundle in your application
>   bundle.unsanitizedScriptURLString:((null))

I don't know how to make it. My android project is running perfectly. But ios project is not running.

cd react-native
react-native git:(master) ✗ open Examples/UIExplorer/UIExplorer.xcodeproj/

Comment: Have you install Xcode properly?

Comment: Of course,i install Xcode already. "react-native init project" ,this way  to create project  i running perfectly in ios and andrioid.Now i want to run Examples in react-native,but i can't run in ios successfully.

Comment: react-native git:(master) ✗ open Examples/UIExplorer/UIExplorer.xcodeproj/

Comment: This is my way to open the project

Comment: @Mr.Chang,Did you solve this issue?

Comment: No,I did not success for ios ,i do not how to do . Are you success for it ?@Moussawi7